# drupal/drupal package versus drupal/core package: deciding the one to use

Tags: composer

Installing Drupal via Composer, I can choose between two packages: [*drupal/drupal*](https://packagist.org/packages/drupal/drupal) and [*drupal/core*](https://packagist.org/packages/drupal/core). What are the differences between them?

(As a side note, why was the package named *drupal/drupal* instead of simply *drupal*?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*drupal/core* is used for a completely Composer-driven Drupal project where your canonical code repository isn't storing Drupal's codebase but pulling it down as you assemble the project where needed (e.g. local dev, CI build, etc.)
Per the README in the [*drupal/core*](https://packagist.org/packages/drupal/core) repository on Packagist:

> This is a [Git subtree](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt) split of [Drupal](https://github.com/drupal/drupal) 8's core directory which can be used to build the directory structure for a Drupal site and has the following advantages over pulling in the entire upstream Drupal repository:
>
> - All the components of the Drupal site including Drupal, contributed modules and themes, as well as external libraries can be pulled in via [Composer](https://getcomposer.org)
> - Drupal and any external libraries can be bootstrapped via Composer (i.e. without installing any modules for the external libraries)
> - One has full control over index.php, .htaccess, robots.txt, etc. as those files will not be overridden by a Drupal core update

[*drupal/drupal*](https://packagist.org/packages/drupal/drupal) is the entire project built from the [core Drupal Git repository](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/). It comes with other pre-made web config you'll need to run the site as if you retrieved the tarball from the [Drupal core project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal). This method is considered **deprecated** and is kept around for legacy reasons.

The *drupal/drupal* name is an artifact of the Drupal packagist repository configuration; you're retrieving a Composer package from the *drupal* vendor (the Drupal community) for the *drupal* project (Drupal core).